# How to import same package from different osgi bundles?

Tags: import, split, osgi, bundle

In my osgi project I have maven-bundle-plugin with instructions to import some path, for example:
    
    org.blah.blah.*
     
And I have two other bundles that export such package.
How to configure my bundle to import org.blah.blah.* from both of them?

Answer (score 11):

You can't import a given package name from more than one bundle. What you could do is Require-Bundle both bundles which will give your bundle access to both packages as a split package with all the inherent issues of split packages and Require-Bundle. See 3.13.3 in the OSGi Core Release 5 spec.

Better would be to refactor (if you can) to avoid split packages.